# How to set alias to columns retrieved with jsonb_to_recordset?

Tags: sql, postgresql, eloquent

I have column "phone" that contains array of objects. For example

```
[
   {
     "id": 8789789789,
     "phone": "111111111",
     "default": true,
     "code": "11",
     "country_code": "US"
   }
]
```

I need to join some of values from one of objects in this array so I use jsonb_to_recordset with cross join lateral for this

```
select * 
from "phones" cross join lateral 
     jsonb_to_recordset(phone) as r(phone jsonb, country_code jsonb)
 where "r.country_code" = ? and "deleted_at" is null
```

Problem here is that the retrieved phone(from object) overwrites initial phone column with json. How can I set aliases for joined columns so they wont overwrite original column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give them new alaises:

```
select p.*,
       r.phone as r_phone,
       r.r_country_code as r_country_code
from "phones" p cross join lateral 
     jsonb_to_recordset(phone) as r(phone jsonb, country_code jsonb)
 where "country_code" = ? and "deleted_at" is null
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I would also like to ask, is it possible to use 'where' statement inside my lateral join? So it will only join record where country_code has value that i need or null(at this moment it joins every object inside array)

Comment: @rusyko . . . The filtering should probably be fine.  I doubt the function is being called on the rows filtered out.